# Python dictionary adding new values in existing key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def add_to_dict(word_to_nexts, word, next_word):
    ''' (dict of {str: set of str}, str, str) -> NoneType

    Update word_to_nexts so that word maps to a set containing
    next_word

    >>> my_dict = {'one':{'day', 'two'}, 'a':{'dog', 'day'}}
    >>> add_to_dict(my_dict, 'one', 'time')
    >>> my_dict == {'one':{'day', 'two', 'time'}, 'a':{'dog', 'day'}}
    True

    '''
```

I wonder, is there any built-in method that I can use for finishing this task?
I was trying to do

```
    for i in word_to_nexts:
        if i == word:
            word_to_nexts[i].add(next_word)
```

however, I did not get the boolean value I expected.

Comment: I use pydash its helpful https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pydash.objects.set_

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What is the problem?

Comment: The above code works, however, I did not get True as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_to_nexts = defaultdict(set)
word_to_nexts['one'].add('dog')
word_to_nexts['one'].add('time')
word_to_nexts['two'].add('face')
print(word_to_nexts)
print(word_to_nexts == {'one':{'time','dog'}, 'two': {'face'}})
```

outputs

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'one': {'time', 'dog'}, 'two': {'face'}})
True
```

If you instead wants to use plain dictionaries, you could always wrap it in a function:

```
def getset(d, key):
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = set()
    return d[key]

word_to_nexts = {}
getset(word_to_nexts, 'one').add('dog')
getset(word_to_nexts, 'one').add('time')
getset(word_to_nexts, 'two').add('face')
print(word_to_nexts)
print(word_to_nexts == {'one':{'time','dog'}, 'two': {'face'}})
```

Comment: If I can not use any libraries, how could I solve this by logic?